# kivy - Bind button to spawn additional instance of widget?

Tags: python, button, widget, kivy

I've created two `Scatter` widgets that can be resized, what I'm looking for is a way to spawn more `Scatter` widgets (potentially up to 20-ish) each time a button is pressed. I tried to write and bind an `addfunction()` to a `Button`, but it doesn't seem to work.

I'm looking for a way to spawn a new instance of the `Scatterer` widget (along with the child widget `Drawer` which has a `canvas` to show it's occupied space) when prompted.

Here's my python code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class Scatterer(Scatter):
    pass
class Drawer(FloatLayout):
    pass
class MainWindowWidget(FloatLayout):
    def addfunction(*args):
        root = MainWindowWidget()

        s = Scatterer()
        d = Drawer()

        root.add_widget(s)
        s.add_widget(d)
        print("button is pressed")

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):

        return MainWindowWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

and my .kv file:

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

<MainWindowWidget>

    Scatterer:
        id: scatter2
        size: 80, 80
        Drawer:
            size: scatter2.size 
    Scatterer:
        id: scatter1
        size: 80, 80
        Drawer:
            size: scatter1.size 
    Button:
        text: 'press'
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 100, 100
        pos: 100, 0

        on_release: root.addfunction()
<Scatterer>:
    do_rotation: False
    size_hint: None, None
    size: self.size

    canvas.after:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 0, 0.5
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

<Drawer>:
    size: self.size
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 1, 0, 0.3
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

Answer (score 2):

> root = MainWindowWidget()

Your problem is that you write this, then add the new Scatter to `root`, but then never do anything with root so it never gets displayed.

You don't want to add the Scatterer to a *new* MainWindowWidget, but to the *current* one whose method is running to make the new Scatterer. So replace the declaration of your method with

```
def addfunction(self, *args):


    s = Scatterer()
    d = Drawer()

    self.add_widget(s)
    s.add_widget(d)
    print("button is pressed")
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, however `d.size` was `1,1` so I had to add `s.size = 80, 80` and `d.size = s.size` to get what I wanted